# java.util.MissingResourceException: Could not load any resource bundle by com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.XMLErrorResources

Tags: quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I try to build an AWS Lambda handler with quarkus/graalVM. The handler is supposed to consume SQS Messages from a queue (not as an SQSEvent). I added the dependencies
- quarkus-amazon-lambda
- quarkus-camel-aws-sqs
- quarkus-amazon-dynamodb (to get SSL configuration somewhat)
- aws-lambda-java-events
- quarkus-jaxb

I already added some reflection hints for Logging and for the com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl, but now I get the above exception about a missing resource. Can resource bundles be specified somehow in the reflection configuration as well or is there another way to go?

```java
Failed to run lambda: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to unmarshall error response (Could not load any resource bundle by com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.XMLErrorResources). Response Code: 400, Response Text: Bad Request
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1707)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1366)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1112)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:769)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:725)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:531)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2215)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2182)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2171)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1601)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1573)
at edeka.digital.MarketHandler.handleRequest(MarketHandler.java:51)
at edeka.digital.MarketHandler.handleRequest(MarketHandler.java:15)
at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AmazonLambdaRecorder$2.run(AmazonLambdaRecorder.java:65)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:473)
at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Could not load any resource bundle by com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.XMLErrorResources
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.SecuritySupport$8.run(SecuritySupport.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.SecuritySupport$8.run(SecuritySupport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.SecuritySupport.getResourceBundle(SecuritySupport.java:174)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.SecuritySupport.getResourceBundle(SecuritySupport.java:164)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.XMLMessages.createXMLMessage(XMLMessages.java:85)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.ObjectPool.getInstance(ObjectPool.java:144)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.StringBufferPool.get(StringBufferPool.java:46)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.getStringValue(DOM2DTM.java:823)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects.XNodeSet.getStringFromNode(XNodeSet.java:219)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects.XNodeSet.str(XNodeSet.java:282)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.getResultAsType(XPathImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:272)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:361)
at com.amazonaws.util.XpathUtils.evaluateAsString(XpathUtils.java:603)
at com.amazonaws.util.XpathUtils.asString(XpathUtils.java:245)
at com.amazonaws.transform.StandardErrorUnmarshaller.parseErrorCode(StandardErrorUnmarshaller.java:95)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.transform.PurgeQueueInProgressExceptionUnmarshaller.unmarshall(PurgeQueueInProgressExceptionUnmarshaller.java:35)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.transform.PurgeQueueInProgressExceptionUnmarshaller.unmarshall(PurgeQueueInProgressExceptionUnmarshaller.java:24)
at com.amazonaws.http.DefaultErrorResponseHandler.createAse(DefaultErrorResponseHandler.java:94)
at com.amazonaws.http.DefaultErrorResponseHandler.handle(DefaultErrorResponseHandler.java:71)
at com.amazonaws.http.DefaultErrorResponseHandler.handle(DefaultErrorResponseHandler.java:47)
at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handleAse(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:53)
at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:41)
at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:26)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1693)
... 20 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, two minutes later I found it myself:

`-H:IncludeResourceBundles=com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.XMLErrorResources`